# ReactJS useLocation() with history.push -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that uses `location.state.data` to pass data through the `history.push` params like so

Component 1 thats pushing the data

```
    history.push({
        pathname: '/chat',
        state: {
            data: location.state.data,
        },
    })
```

Component 2 that accepted the data

```
const location = useLocation()
...
<IonCardSubtitle>{location.state.data.contactPerson}</IonCardSubtitle>
<IonCardSubtitle>{location.state.data.email}</IonCardSubtitle>
<IonCardTitle>{location.state.data.name}</IonCardTitle>
...
```

Now, when i switch from component 2 to any other route using `history.push` location is becoming undefined (which I think i understand), but component 2, which i dont care about anymore because **I am going to Component 3**, is becoming undefined.

What am I doing wrong? I would really like to pass the params programatically without the use of the `location` hook.

[image: image of error]

Comment: you can ```console.log(location.state.data)``` to see what is ```location.state.data``` before you consume it

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have had something to do with Ionic. I switched to the IonicNav which is a wrapper of browserrouter, and all the problems went away “¯_(ツ)_/¯“